# PressedListener event for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to have `Press` event listener for my tabLayout.

Based on the tabLayout item which is pressed I want to highlight another view in my layout.

I know we have `addOnTabSelectedListener` but I want to have `PressedListener`.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get each tab views and set touch listener on each, didnt try it my self pls try and let me knw

```
val tabStrip = tab.getChildAt(0)
    if (tabStrip is ViewGroup) {
        val childCount = tabStrip.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val tabView = tabStrip.getChildAt(i)
            tabView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Log.d("touchEvent","touched $i")
                }
                return@setOnTouchListener true
            }
        }
    }
```

in java

```
   final View tabStrip = ((TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab)).getChildAt(0);
    int childCount = ((ViewGroup) tabStrip).getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View tabView = ((ViewGroup) tabStrip).getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        tabView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("onTouch", "touched " + finalI);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Index of for loop should be the index of tabs

Comment: We can not access `i` in `onTouch` overriden method, unless index is final which is impossible.

Comment: You can copy the index variable to another final variable inside the loop

Comment: which boolean did you return inside onTouch?